# Best approach in Java - Spring Boot API to provide a file (.xlxs) with almost 1 million of registers?

Tags: java, spring-boot, download, base64, apache-poi

Currently I have within my API a service that provides the base 64 in text of an .xlxs file that can have from a thousand or two thousand to a million records.

I am using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and in short, all the services list the records to pass to excel, and then I create the excel...

```
public static SXSSFWorkbook toExcel(List<?> listToExcel) {
        String[] headers = {"Column A",  .... , "Column n"};

        SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(200);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Any Sheet Name");
        Row header = sheet.createRow(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            Cell headerCell = header.createCell(i);
            headerCell.setCellValue(headers[i]);
            headerCell.setCellStyle(getStyle(workbook));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < listToExcel.size(); i++) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(i + 1);
            ObjectX report = (ObjectX) listToExcel.get(i);

            Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue(report.getState());
            // for each property of the object I create a cell 
            // and finally a row in a for
```

at the end y just return this woorkbook in base64 in the service

```
Workbook workbook = ObjectX.toExcel(listFromDatabase);
        return ok(toBase64(workbook), "Consulta Exitosa");
```

I'm aware about to :

1. is this ok in resource optimization?
2. is the fastest generator?
3. will it affect the java heap memory or something I don't have visibility of?

Comment: It's an Excel file. Why are you Base64ing it instead of returning it as bytes?

Comment: How long will it take to create a large Excel file?  Could the client abandon the connection (timeout) before starting to return a result?  Could multiple users request large Excel files to be created?  Consider streaming directly to the response instead of building the entire Excel then returning the whole object.  Or maybe stream to blob storage, and return just the storage location to the client, and the client can download the file without going through the app.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean by Streaming directly means return the data in the original mapped format (like json) ?